# Hidden Markov Model Notation

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I have some background in machine learning and I also just completed a face-identification excersize using support vector machine.  I am in the process of trying to convert this exercise to HMM, but I am having problems understanding the notation and how to use it (I am using Kevin Murphy’s HMM package).

I am given about a 50 gray scale images of 6 different people (numbered 1-6).  Each image is a 10 pixels by 10 pixels and each pixel can have values between 0-255 (8 bit gray scale). The goal is that I will be able to classify a new image to one of the 6 faces.

My approach is to take each image and make it a long vector of length 100  elements each is a pixel value . Now, I am getting to the confusing part.  The notations I am using is as follows:

N : Number of observation symbols - I understand that the hidden state is the person’s face (i.e 1-6), therefore, there are 6 hidden states so N=6.

T : Length of observation sequence – is this equal to a 50 ?  I am not sure what this represents

M: Number of observation symbols – is this equal to a 100 ? Does the term of “observation symbol” refer to the number of elements in the vector representing the observation?

O : Number of observations – what does this represent?  In every example they use a single binary observed value and they make this to be 2 (i.e on or off).  What would this be in my case ?

I greatly appreciate the help

Comment: I would say this is more appropriate for stats.SE.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/